# Some questions in STL map and list using in c++

Tags: c++, stl, memory-leaks

Hello I would like to ask about:
I have map and list

Questions:

Is the following implementation of distructor right :

```
   for (map<string,SymbolTableNode*>::iterator i = symbolTable.begin();
                         i != symbolTable.end(); ++i)
   {
       delete i;
   }
   symbolTable.clear();
```

or I miss some memory?

About list:

```
   list<MyClass2*> mylist;
   mylist.push_front(new MyClass());
   mylist.pop_front();
```

does pop invoke delete? or I have memory leakage in this case? If there is the leakage problem then what can I do to avoid it?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you should delete value of iterator i, not itself.

Comment: Thank you very much Andreas and all others it helped me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to have a list of pointers ? Can't you have a plain list ?

```
list<MyClass> mylist;
mylist.push_front(MyClass());
```

It will save you the pain of memory management.

If you need pointers, then use smart pointers or pointer containers from boost : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html

Comment: Yes I need pointers because i would like to change the elements in the list

Comment: That has nothing to do, you can change objects that are in the list. You can do my_list.back().value = 42;

Comment: Tried it it works it means that my_list.back() returns reference to value , and I thought that if it holds the element by value then it returns it the same way.

Answer (score 4):

No `pop_front` won't invoke delete. You'll have to delete the pointer yourself before you pop it.:

```
list<MyClass2*> mylist;
mylist.push_front(new MyClass());
delete mylist.front();
mylist.pop_front();
```

And the destructor should probably be:

```
delete i->second;
```

Answer (score 3):

you have a leak. See smart pointers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer)

More explicitely:

```
list<boost::shared_ptr<MyClass2> > mylist;


mylist.pop(); // now it will invoke delete
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete i;
```

Wrong.

This should be this:

```
delete i->second;
```

Because `i` points to a pair.

Comment: Also, because `i` is not a pointer, but an iterator (so `delete i` shouldn't even compile).

Answer (score -1):

Nawaz - You are wrong.

Iterator element for a map is a pair so proper delete call is:

```
delete (*i).second;
```

P.S.
Ok - now I see You have fixed this :)

Comment: what's the difference between (i*).second and i->second when i is an iterator on the map ?

Comment: -1 for saying that `delete i->second` doesn't do what `delete (*i).second` does and for not knowing that they're exactly same!

Comment: Same code generated for STL pair, but worth mentioning is that the -> operator can be overloaded in C++ (though the . cannot) so there could be a difference for other classes.

Comment: Nawaz! I wrote, that You were wrong in Your FIRST answer.
Look at my "P.S" added later.